# Why is the "where" query in rails returning a different object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm testing chats between users in my app. I'm using RSpec and FactoryGirl

The test that's not passing:

```
it "creates a chat if one does not exist" do
  bob = create(:user, username: "bob")
  dan = create(:user, username: "dan")
  new_chat = Chat.create(user_id: @dan.id, chatted_user_id: bob.id)
  expect(Chat.where("chatted_user_id = ?", bob.id).first).to equal(new_chat)
end
```

The failure message says:

```
Failure/Error: expect(Chat.where("chatted_user_id = ?", bob.id).first).to equal(new_chat)

   expected #<Chat:70120833243920> => #<Chat id: 2, user_id: 2, chatted_user_id: 3>
        got #<Chat:70120833276240> => #<Chat id: 2, user_id: 2, chatted_user_id: 3>

   Compared using equal?, which compares object identity,
   but expected and actual are not the same object. Use
   `expect(actual).to eq(expected)` if you don't care about
   object identity in this example.
```

Why is my query returning a different object id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equal` checks object identity. The objects you are testing are two objects (instances) referencing the same record, but they are actually different objects from a Ruby virtual machine point of view.

You should use

```
expect(Chat.where("chatted_user_id = ?", bob.id).first).to eq(new_chat)
```

To better understand the problem, look at the following example

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > "foo".object_id
 => 70117320944040 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > "foo".object_id
 => 70117320962820
```

Here I'm creating two identical strings. They are identical, but not equal because they are actually two different objects.

```
2.0.0-p353 :008 > "foo" == "foo"
 => true 
2.0.0-p353 :009 > "foo".equal? "foo"
 => false
```

That's the same issue affecting your test. `equal` checks if two objects are actually the same at the object_id level. But what you really want to know is if they are the same record.

Comment: Thanks Simone! So is == the same as eq? And are they just checking the "value" of the object? Also, can you suggest any further readings on this in relation to ActiveRecord instances?

Comment: Yes, `eq` is the RSpec matcher for `==`.